# Call PHP extension function from web page

Tags: php

I have done and installed PHP extension `skeleton.so` according [manual](http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-php-extension-development-via-php-cpp/) with function :

```
void helloWorld (Php::Parameters &params)
{
    std::string name=params[0];
    std::cout<<"Hello "<<name<<"!"<<std::endl;

}
```

It works fine if I call php from command line:

```
php scr.php
```

scr.php content:

```
echo helloWorld('Taylor');
```

But I can't make it run on web page. 
web page content:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
echo  helloWorld('Taylor') ;
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Page is empty.

How to enable PHP extension in web page?

Comment: [php include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: the original post talks about building an extension - they should not need to include anything.

Answer (score 1):

what errors are appearing in the error log?

have you restarted your web-server to make sure it's picked up the new extension is loaded?

if you do

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

in your web page does it indicate that extension is loaded?

Comment: This gives emptypage in web browser. Loks my php not working at all